# How do I tell Elasticsearch to get the column names from the first line of a file?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I just started using Elasticsearch/logstash.

I have 3 different files with a common id. Each file contains the column names on the first line, for example:

```
header1,header2,header3,header4
1234,data2,data3,data4
1235,data2,data3,data4
1236,data2,data3,data4
```

How can I tell Elasticsearch to get the first line as column names?

Also, how can I do some research in Elastic using the common id between the files, for example `q:column=data group by id`?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are outdated as of CSV filter plugin version **3.0.8** (maybe earlier). Now you can do this:

`filter {
  csv {
    autodetect_column_names => true
  }
}`

In case it's not working as expected, you'll have to add `pipeline.workers: 1` into your `logstash.yml` file.

See: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-csv/issues/65

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have csv data.  Logstash provides a csv filter, but it doesn't handle header rows.

There is a new [csv codec](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-codec-csv), but it's listed as not ready for production.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the below mentioned code in the .confgig file . You have to explicitly mention the column names in the config file .

```
filter {
csv {
    columns => [
      "YearMonth",
      "ProjectCode",
      "EmpNo",
      "RevenueCreditUnit",
      "Revenue",
      "dtLoad"

    ]
    separator => ","
    remove_field => ["message"]
    }
}
```

Keep searching , there might be a better way .